# Return the specific column for a model in Laravel and convert to Json

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

There are two tables which is many to many relation:

User:

```
<?php class User extends Eloquent {

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Role');
    } 
}
```

Role:

```
class Role extends Eloquent {

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }

}
```

I have no problem to get the users with all the fields and convert it to json:

```
    $role = Role::find($id)->users()->get()->toArray();        
    var_dump($role);
```

But when I'm trying to only retrieve the user id field, I encountered a problem to convert it to json, here is my code: (If I don't call ->get()->toArray(), the var_dump has no problem.)

```
    $role = Role::find($id)->users()->select(array('id'))->get()->toArray(); 
    var_dump($role);
```

Any idea? Thanks

**Edit:**

The error message:

Slim Application Errorbody{margin:0;padding:30px;font:12px/1.5 Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;}h1{margin:0;font-size:48px;font-weight:normal;line-height:48px;}strong{display:inline-block;width:65px;}

## Slim Application Error

The application could not run because of the following error:

### Details

**Type:** Illuminate\Database\QueryException**Code:** 23000**Message:** SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous (SQL: select `id`, `users`.*, `role_user`.`role_id` as `pivot_role_id`, `role_user`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id` from `users` inner join `role_user` on `users`.`id` = `role_user`.`user_id` where `role_user`.`role_id` = role_1)**File:** /Users/Public/Website/cast/vendor/illuminate/database/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php**Line:** 555

### Trace

```
#0 /Users/Public/Website/cast/vendor/illuminate/database/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(283): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('select id, u...', Array, Object(Closure))
<div>#1 /Users/Public/Website/cast/vendor/illuminate/database/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1312): Illuminate\Database\Connection->select('selectid,u...', Array)
#2 /Users/Public/Website/cast/vendor/illuminate/database/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1302): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->runSelect()
#3 /Users/Public/Website/cast/vendor/illuminate/database/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1289): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->getFresh(Array)
#4 /Users/Public/Website/cast/vendor/illuminate/database/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(416): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->get(Array)
#5 /Users/Public/Website/cast/vendor/illuminate/database/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php(145): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->getModels()
#6 /Users/Public/Website/cast/app/controllers/Api/v1/TestController.php(24): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany->get()
#7 [internal function]: Api\v1\TestController->testRelation('role_1')
#8 /Users/Public/Website/cast/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(173): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#9 [internal function]: Slim\Route->Slim{closure}('role_1')
#10 /Users/Public/Website/cast/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(462): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#11 /Users/Public/Website/cast/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Slim.php(1326): Slim\Route->dispatch()
#12 /Users/Public/Website/cast/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/Flash.php(85): Slim\Slim->call()
#13 /Users/Public/Website/cast/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/MethodOverride.php(92): Slim\Middleware\Flash->call()
#14 /Users/Public/Website/cast/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/PrettyExceptions.php(67): Slim\Middleware\MethodOverride->call()
#15 /Users/Public/Website/cast/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Slim.php(1271): Slim\Middleware\PrettyExceptions->call()
#16 /Users/Public/Website/cast/vendor/illuminate/support/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(205): Slim\Slim->run()
#17 /Users/Public/Website/cast/public/index.php(4): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('run', Array)
#18 /Users/Public/Website/cast/public/index.php(4): SlimFacades\App::run()
#19 {main}
```

**Edit 2:**

The error was caused by the field in select statement. I changed it to:

```
$role = Role::find($id)->users()->select(array('users.id'))->get()->toArray(); 
var_dump($role);
```

It now returns some value. But unfortunately it still returns all the fields instead of only 'users.id' field.

Comment: What is "Model"? Shouldnt Role extend Eloquent?

Comment: Sorry. It's a Eloquent model. (I'm using SlimStarter which extend the Eloquent).

Comment: What is the "problem"/"error" you get when you try to run the command?

Comment: I think I should use 'users.id' in my case.

Comment: After I fixed the filed name problem, I can get the result. But unfortunately it still return all the fields instead of the field I select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Taylor Otwell it is not currently possible to select the columns to return with belongsToMany: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/issues/2679

What about this solution:

Role

```
class Role extends Eloquent {

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User')->select('id');
    }

}
```

And then

```
$roles = Role::find($id)->with('users')->get();
$users = $roles->users;
$usersId = $users->lists('id');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. At first I should change the 'id' to 'users.id' in select('id'). But the $users = $roles->users(); return nothing.

Comment: It is `$users = $roles->users;` if you made a typo

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final working version based on Antoine Augusti's answer:

Role.php:

```
<?php

class Role extends Model {

    public function users()
    {
        //return $this->belongsToMany('User');
        return $this->belongsToMany('User')->select('users.id');
    }    
}
```

My code to list all the users id:

```
    $roles = Role::find($id);
    $users = $roles->users();
    $usersId = $users->lists('users.id');
    var_dump($usersId);
```

The usersId will show only the user id in an array. But I think the $users still include all the fields.

Anyway it solved my problem although it's not perfect. Thanks Antoine Augusti.